# TypeError: interaction.options.getSubcommand is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I have made a all-in-one moderation bot by compiling certain codes. Recently, I was adding Ticket-System to my bot and it showed me this error. Although, I tried all the fixes I could find on the internet but still couldn't solve it.

Here is my code -->

**ticket-config.js**

```
const { Util, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const configOptions = require('../../configOptions');

module.exports = {
    name: "ticketconfig",
    description: "Configuration ticket system.",
    options: configOptions,
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    run: async(interaction, client) => {
        const replyMessage = {
            content: "Config has been set!"
        }
        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'message') {
            const message = interaction.options.getString('message');
            const content = interaction.options.getString('content') || null;
            let data = await client.db.get('config', interaction.guild.id);
            if (!data) data = {};
            data.message = message;
            data.content = content;
            await client.db.set('config', interaction.guild.id, data);
            return interaction.reply(replyMessage)
        }
```

**configOptions.js**

```
module.exports = [
    {
        name: "message",
        description: "Configuration your ticket message",
        type: 1,
        options: [
            {
                name: "message",
                description: "The message to sent in ticket",
                type: 3,
                required: true
            },
            {
                name: "content",
                description: "content will be appeared above embed message, use /variables command to see all available variables.",
                type: 3
            }
        ]
    },
```

**./handler/index.js**

```
module.exports = async (client) => {

    const eventFiles = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/events/*.js`);
    eventFiles.map((value) => require(value));


    const slashCommands = await globPromise(
        `${process.cwd()}/SlashCommands/*/*.js`
    );

    const arrayOfSlashCommands = [];
    slashCommands.map((value) => {
        const file = require(value);
        if (!file?.name) return;
        client.slashCommands.set(file.name, file);

        if (["MESSAGE", "USER"].includes(file.type)) delete file.description;
        arrayOfSlashCommands.push(file);
    });
    client.on("ready", async () => {
        await client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to do some basic debugging? Have you checked what your `interaction.options.getSubcommand` is? Try to `console.log` it or check its type: `console.log(typeof interaction.options.getSubcommand)`

Comment: I ran my code with debugging it ran but still faced the same error, what should I do now??

Comment: Thanks for telling me what the value of `interaction.options.getSubcommand` is :)